# How to programmatically determine if the OS we are currently running on is Windows Error Reporting capable?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, windows-error-reporting

I would like to determine if the OS that my program currently running on is Windows Error Reporting capable. I would like to do this using some kind of API.

Windows Error Reporting was introducing from Vista onwards, but I just can't check 
   if(osType == Vista)

because, my code runs on WES 7 and WES 2009 (Windows Embedded Standard).

Is there any way do this?

Thanks a lot for ur help and suggestions:)

Comment: Windows Error Reporting started with Windows XP.: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Error_Reporting

Comment: There's a registry key for it, used to disable it.  Ask at superuser.com

Comment: looks like i can disable the service from registry, but i would like to know whether the service is actually running or supported. how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just attempt to do a LoadLibrary for "wer.dll".  If it succeeds, you have WER.

```
BOOL IsWindowsErrorReportingAvailable()
{
    BOOL fRet = FALSE;

    HMODULE hMod = LoadLibrary("wer.dll");

    fRet = (hMod != NULL);

    if (fRet)
    {
        // make sure the APIs from WER we want to use are available
        fRet = (NULL != GetProcAddress(hMod, L"ReportFault"));
    }

    CloseHandle(hMod);

    return fRet;
}
```